# jQuery cookie not working properly in wordpress

Tags: jquery, html, wordpress, cookies

I make my own accordion menu with `html + jquery` its working perfectly to forth level, then i add a cookie code from net and do some extra work it also work 100% perfectly in html.

My complete HTML + jQuery code reference is in JS-Fiddle [Accordion Menu with Cookie](http://jsfiddle.net/deemi/cdy75fpj/)

Now i merge it in my wordpress menu very carefully, it shows very weird behavior. when i click on plus the sub menus are open and i click on sub category the page goes to that category but the menu is close but when i again open the sub  menu and click on the menu or refresh the page its work. I worried why in wordpress the jquery cookie not working.

Here is jquery cookie + jquery accordion code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {


   // baking cookie ;p
   function set_cookie(ID) {
         document.cookie = ID + "=opened";
   }

   // getting it out from the oven... ;)
   function get_cookies_array() {

       var cookies = {};

       if (document.cookie && document.cookie != '') {
          var split = document.cookie.split(';');
          for (var i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {
              var name_value = split[i].split("=");
              name_value[0] = name_value[0].replace(/^ /, '');
              cookies[decodeURIComponent(name_value[0])] = decodeURIComponent(name_value[1]);
          }
       }

       return cookies;

   }

   // yuck... sorry i don't know how to cook :S
   function unset_cookie(cookie_name) {
        var cookie_date = new Date();
        cookie_date.setTime(cookie_date.getTime() - 1);
        document.cookie = cookie_name += "=; expires=" + cookie_date.toGMTString();
   }

   var tree_id = 0;
   jQuery('ul.b29-tree li:has(ul)').addClass('has-child').prepend('<span class="switch">+</span>').each(function () {
                    tree_id++;
                    jQuery(this).attr('id', 'tree' + tree_id);
                });
   // Accordion code
   jQuery('ul.b29-tree li > span.switch').click(function () {
            var tree_id = jQuery(this).parent().attr('id');
            if (jQuery(this).hasClass('open')) {
                        jQuery(this).parent().find('ul:first').slideUp('fast');
                        jQuery(this).removeClass('open');
                        jQuery(this).text('+');
                        unset_cookie(tree_id)
                    } else {
                        jQuery(this).parent().find('ul:first').slideDown('fast');
                        jQuery(this).text('-');
                        jQuery(this).addClass('open');
                        set_cookie(tree_id)

                    }
                });

                var cookies = get_cookies_array();
                for (var name in cookies) {
                    $('#' + name).find('> ul').css({'display' : 'block'});
                    $('#' + name).find('> span').addClass('open').text('-');
                }

            });
```

I am working in wordpress on my xamp so i can't give you that link but above link is the demo of html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok,

I solve this by my own. I use wordpress `cookiepath` constant and it works on wordpress perfectly.

Here is the jquery code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
                // baking cookie ;p
                function set_cookie(ID) {
                    document.cookie = ID + "=opened; path=<?php echo COOKIEPATH ?>";
                }

                // getting it out from the oven... 
                function get_cookies_array() {
                    var cookies = {};

                    if (document.cookie && document.cookie != '') {
                        var split = document.cookie.split(';');
                        for (var i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {
                            var name_value = split[i].split("=");
                            name_value[0] = name_value[0].replace(/^ /, '');
                            cookies[decodeURIComponent(name_value[0])] = decodeURIComponent(name_value[1]);
                        }
                    }
                    return cookies;
                }

                // yuck... sorry i don't know how to cook :S
                function unset_cookie(cookie_name) {
                    var cookie_date = new Date();
                    cookie_date.setTime(cookie_date.getTime() - 1);
                    document.cookie = cookie_name += "=; expires=" + cookie_date.toGMTString() + "; path=<?php echo COOKIEPATH ?>";
                }

                var tree_id = 0;
                jQuery('ul.wpc-categories li:has(ul)').addClass('has-child').prepend('<span class="switch"><img src="<?php echo plugin_dir_url(__FILE__); ?>/includes/css/images/icon-plus.png" /></span>').each(function () {
                    tree_id++;
                    jQuery(this).attr('id', 'tree' + tree_id);
                });

                jQuery('ul.wpc-categories li > span.switch').click(function () {
                    var tree_id = jQuery(this).parent().attr('id');
                    if (jQuery(this).hasClass('open')) {
                        jQuery(this).parent().find('ul:first').slideUp('fast');
                        jQuery(this).removeClass('open');
                        jQuery(this).html('<img src="<?php echo plugin_dir_url(__FILE__); ?>/includes/css/images/icon-plus.png" />');
                        unset_cookie(tree_id)
                    } else {
                        jQuery(this).parent().find('ul:first').slideDown('fast');
                        jQuery(this).html('<img src="<?php echo plugin_dir_url(__FILE__); ?>/includes/css/images/icon-minus.png" />');
                        jQuery(this).addClass('open');
                        set_cookie(tree_id)
                    }
                });

                var cookies = get_cookies_array();
                for (var name in cookies) {
                    jQuery('#' + name).find('> ul').css({'display' : 'block'});
                    jQuery('#' + name).find('> span').addClass('open').html('<img src="<?php echo plugin_dir_url(__FILE__); ?>/includes/css/images/icon-minus.png" />');
                }
            });
```